# Why is this PHP download script failing only on Android

Tags: php, android, download

I have a simple script that allows someone to download a movie file to their device.  The code works well on everything I've tested except for Andriod.  The Android device butchers the name and the file extension.  It might call the file 2.qt or .bin.  Why is this failing?

```
<?php

        if(isset($_GET['filename'])) {

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: movie/quicktime');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("$file"));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile("$file"); 
    } else {
        echo "Link: <a href='test.php?filename=test.mov'>Download Video</a>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the filenames had spaces, and Android doesn't like that. I removed the spaces and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Because Android doesn't natively support Quicktime, an Apple technology.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=04e2ade03aed94b7&hl=en) It's also very possible that the client used to download this app isn't respecting the filename set on the http envelope as the name it uses to write the file to the filesystem, as there is [nothing forcing it to](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device).

Comment: I get that Android doesn't natively support Quicktime, but that's not my concern here.  I just want to be able to download the file, I'm not concerned with playing it.   You say there is nothing forcing the client to name the filename to the name provided in the http envelope.  Is there a way to force it to?

Comment: I read the link you provided, I don't think it helps me.  It's talking about writing an app for Android in Java, which is not what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to write a php web app that allows the device to download the file.  Maybe you're saying that I can't force the browser to use the filename I provide unless I write an android app?

Comment: Yep, that's what the snippet was meant to illuminate. It's hard to say how the browser in question (either the native one or Doplhin, perhaps) has implemented the file download operation, but it's very possible that it does not use the filename attribute you provide or rewrites it.

Comment: The problem was that the file names had spaces, and Andriod doesn't like that.  I removed the spaces and everything is fine.